# Google App Engine (Java) Logging Levels 1.7.4 Reduction

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm trying to reduce the noise level of my dev environment.  I have tried setting the logging level in my `logging.properties` file to `.level=SEVERE` but I'm still receiving logs like the following:

```
Dec 24, 2012 2:47:16 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFO: Logging to JettyLogger(null) via com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger
Dec 24, 2012 2:47:16 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader     readAppEngineWebXml
INFO: Successfully processed C:\Ws\testproject\war\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
Dec 24, 2012 2:47:16 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader readConfigXml
INFO: Successfully processed C:\Ws\apphosting\war\WEB-INF/web.xml
```

Does anyone know how to reduce these **INFO** logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the following statement to your `/war/WEB-INF/logging.properties`:

```
com.your_package_name.your_app_name.server.level = SEVERE
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much.  They must have changed something in 1.7.4 I have never had to do this before.

Comment: Is this documented somewhere? I have the same issue but can't seem to reduce the logging. what is meant by "your_package_name"? Lets say most of my application lives in "com.myapp" and the application name is "myapp". I tried com.myapp.myapp.server.level, com.com.myapp.myapp.server.level, myapp.server.level, com.myapp.server.level. None of these seem to reduce the logging in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Notice the second line of the default `logging.properties` file shown below. It states *All App Engine logging is through java.util.logging*.

```
# A default java.util.logging configuration.
# (All App Engine logging is through java.util.logging by default).
#
# To use this configuration, copy it into your application's WEB-INF
# folder and add the following to your appengine-web.xml:
#
# <system-properties>
#   <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
# </system-properties>
#

# Set the default logging level for all loggers to WARNING
.level = WARNING
```

You can find the **documentation** for that [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Level.html). Look at the Field Summary section for all the possibilities.